# Change a Ul list item by Jquery but no change Sub list

Tags: jquery

How to Change the List Item of an Ul List Item. But not changing its Sub List item.

```
<ul id="list">
      <li>
        Main Item 1
        <ul>
          <li>Sub Item 1</li>
          <li>Sub Item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Main Item 2
        <ul>
          <li>Sub Item 1</li>
          <li>Sub Item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Comment: The best solution is to put a `<span>` around what you want to change, so you can write a selector that finds it.

Comment: Hello sir, 

Do you mean like that?

<ul id="list">
      <li>
        <span>Main Item 1</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Sub Item 1</li>
          <li>Sub Item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Main Item 2</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Sub Item 1</li>
          <li>Sub Item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. Then you can do `$("#list > li:eq(1) > span").text("New text")`

Comment: Hello sir, Its working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You just point at direct children like you would do in css like this

```
$("#list > li")
```

Comment: Hi sir, if i do that it will change also its child elements (sub ul elements)